# Sending a HTTP POST Request

Tags: java, xml, siri-xml

I am trying to send a request to get public transport information. Here's a screenshot of an example below, stating that I must send an XML request to the site, defining the method and the service reference (in the example it's StopMonitoringRequest and 020035811).

[image: Instructions]

So far I have managed to connect to the service, but I have no idea what to do from here. I have so far done this...

```
String user = "";
String pass = "";                        
String url = "http://nextbus.mxdata.co.uk/nextbuses/1.0/1";

String authString = user + ":" + pass;
byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);

HttpURLConnection  connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
connection.setRequestProperty( "charset", "utf-8");
connection.setUseCaches(false);
connection.setDoOutput(true);

InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

int numCharsRead;
char[] charArray = new char[1024];
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while ((numCharsRead = isr.read(charArray)) > 0) {
    sb.append(charArray, 0, numCharsRead);
}

String result = sb.toString();
System.out.print(result);
```

...receiving this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Siri version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.siri.org.uk/">
<ServiceDelivery>
<ResponseTimestamp>2015-11-08T20:33:03.574Z</ResponseTimestamp>
</ServiceDelivery>
</Siri>
```

How do I enter the required parameters and method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I had to do was create a HttpPost and set the xml request up as an entity, binding it to the post. Here is the code, in case anyone wants to request information via HTTP POST using XML, outputting the XML as a string:

```java
// basic autthorization security 
String url = "http://nextbus.mxdata.co.uk/nextbuses/1.0/1";
String authString = "<username>:<password>";
byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);

DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
post.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
StringEntity input = new StringEntity(request);
input.setContentType("text/xml");
post.setEntity(input);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String unformattedXML = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```